# magento 2.4.6 plugin final_price.phtml override issue

Tags: plugins, magento2

I deleted all pluggins and 3 template files below:
rm -rf /var/www/html/app/code/*;
rm /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml;
rm /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml;
rm /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml;
only one final_price.phtml left:
fileA: /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

then upgrade,compile,deploy,cache clean,permission granted;
at frontend , product#1234 shows final price $35, I modified fileA and set the final price as $final_price=40, and added die("final_price=$final_price");
ran above php command lines again;at frontend , product#1234 showed "final price= 40", then commented out die("final_price= $final_price");
ran above php command lines again;at frontend , product#1234 showed final price $40 but changed to $35 immediately,
what php/phtml/js files overrode fileA ?

thank you in advance

Felix Chen

customized /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml set the final price as $40,
expected return $40, yes, it return $40, but was replaced with $35 immediately which is original value.